# Rails - overriding name route parameters - GLOBALLY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails(4.2.6) application that has tables like `companies (id, serial...), user (id, serial, company_id...)`, where serial is a random generated 5-20 character long string and unique per table. What I am trying to achieve is to have routes like `/companies/:serial` and `/users/:serial`...

I have read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters), and can do the following in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :companies, param: :serial
resources :users, param: :serial
```

Now, that's not too DRY... Is there a way to do this globally? I know that I could have this in one line (`resources :companies, :users, param: :serial`), but I have other tables, in other namespaces, to which I would like to apply the rule also.

Another thing that I thought of was to have the serial as primary key but I prefer the auto-incrementing integer, and don't want to litter my db with columns like `user.company_serial` with 10-20 character long values...

I have tried to make a scope with `param: :serial` around my resources:

```
scope param: :serial do
  resources :companies
  ...
end
```

like with `path_names` (read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments) in the documentation) but that didn't had the desired effect, instead added `params[:param]` with a symbol value `:serial` for some reason that I don't really understand.

I also know about the existance of the method `to_param`, but if I understood well, I should use it in the models, so I would have to write the same code as many times as many models I have.

Comment: Being explicit on each table is not necessarily a bad thing. Once in a while DRY is taken a little too far in Ruby (go read paperclip source code). I think each table explicitly defining it's serial resources in a local space is fine. Combing the first two lines into one seems practical though.

Comment: @Pyrce, you are right, but I would like to apply the rule for the whole application and I feel as if a sheperd started enumerating the sheep like 'sheep1 is white, sheep2 is white, sheep3 is white...' with all the 400 he has instead of saying that all sheep are white... After all, that's what I'm going to do if there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this is submit serial in a URL as you would have done with the id param, `params[:id]` and use that in the controller.

```
Company.find_by_serial(params[:id)
```

You won't need to change routes, just the controller actions.  This can be dried up, too.

You can do this by explicitly passing serial, or by adding the to_param method.  If you add `to_param` to the model, it will always use this in every place it generates the route where it would have used the id and save you some work.  If there is ever a place you would rather use the id (I prefer this in some controllers, like admin controllers), then you have to explicitly pass it or work around that.

Comment: Yeah, good one. I have thought of that too, only it seemed to me a little hacky, and I felt sure Rails would have an 'official' way to dry it up. Besides if I look upon that code in - say - two years, I may confuse myself with the lines `find_by_serial(params[:id])`

Comment: Yeah - agreed.  I looked for a while at the scope method and it doesn't seem to take the param option and pass it down to the individual resources calls.  I would have expected that too.